# .net 4.0 webpage button click event firing twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a 4.0 webpage with a button click that runs a server side process that takes about 5-10 seconds to run. I thought I’d be smart and search for some code that made the button hide and showed an animated gif image while the process was running.
 I got this working but started to notice “file being used by another process” errors being thrown server side (part of the process is deleting a directory). I debugged through and started to see what appeared to be a second button event click being fired at the same time. Turns out that the piece of Js code I added to refresh the page to allow the animated gif to run seems to be firing the server click event a second time. I had to call the Js SetTimeOut() method to get the gif image running, it's this that is appearing to cause the problem.
 
I did a bit of searching to try to find a different  approach to getting the animated gif to run, but couldn’t find one, so I went for the ambulance at the bottom of the cliff approach and decided to add a server side timestamp into session and only proceed with my code if it is more than 20 seconds since session was last set.
I’ve had some very erratic results with this approach and any input would be appreciated.

1. Is there a better way I can get the gif running?
2. Has anyone else come across this issue of the event firing twice?
3. Why should my lock not work first time through?

Any suggestion of a better approach to do this is appreciated, Thanks!

Logging results:

First time through (no session existing)

2011-06-21 11:46:14.8968|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 1 & Locked = False
2011-06-21 11:46:14.8968|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 2 & Locked = True
2011-06-21 11:46:19.0619|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 1 & Locked = False
2011-06-21 11:46:19.0619|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 2 & Locked = True
2011-06-21 11:46:23.1959|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 3 & Locked = True
2011-06-21 11:46:28.8119|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 3 & Locked = True

Run again:

2011-06-21 11:49:47.7798|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 1 & Locked = False
2011-06-21 11:49:47.7798|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 2 & Locked = True
2011-06-21 11:49:55.9697|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 3 & Locked = True
2011-06-21 11:49:59.8697|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 1 & Locked = True
2011-06-21 11:49:59.8697|DEBUG|FileViewer.copyfiles|Count = 3 & Locked = True

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PostBackOptions optionsSubmit = new PostBackOptions(btnGo);
        btnGo.OnClientClick = "HideControlOnClick(this);";
        btnGo.OnClientClick += ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(optionsSubmit);
    }
}
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool locked = true;

    if (Session["ClickTime"] == null || (DateTime)Session["ClickTime"] < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-20))
    {
        Session["ClickTime"] = DateTime.Now;
        locked = false;
    }

    WriteToLog(1, locked);

    if (Page.IsValid && !locked)
    {
        locked = true;

        WriteToLog(2, locked);

        // Do all my processing
    }

    WriteToLog(3, locked);
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function HideControlOnClick(btnGo) 
    {
        // IE uses className for the css property.        
        btnGo.setAttribute('className', 'hide');

        document.getElementById('MainContent_imgWait').setAttribute('className', 'show');

        setTimeout("UpdateImg('MainContent_imgWait','Images/loading.gif');",50);
    }
    function UpdateImg(ctrl, imgsrc) 
    {
        var img = document.getElementById(ctrl);
        img.src = imgsrc;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, you can't just call a variable 'locked' and have it work with multiple threads.

Comment: yes, agreed, that is why I've set variable locked based on session variable"ClickTime" which should cross different threads.

Comment: I would say, you did bind the event twice.. in the aspx and the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better use some web debugger tools to track the request. I suggest use the [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that issue here is probably nothing to do with animated gif but button being pressed twice (i.e. two clicks getting registered instead one). You can try disabling the button to supress the second click (yet another way is to have flag at button level) - for example,

```
btnGo.OnClientClick = "return HideControlOnClick(this);";


function HideControlOnClick(btnGo) 
{
   if (btnGo["My_Is_Clicked"]) {
      // already clicked, ignore
      return false;
   }
   btnGo["My_Is_Clicked"] = true;
   ...
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a client double click because as soon as I remove the         setTimeout("UpdateImg('MainContent_imgWait','Images/loading.gif');",50); method call from the Js block the duplicate call stops but the gif image won't run.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by dropping all of the relevant controls into an update pannel, this seems to allow the animated gif to run without calling the  setTimeout("UpdateImg('MainContent_imgWait','Images/loading.gif');",50); JS method. Working fine now with the server event only firing once.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you're using a server side button control (since you're referencing it server side), and those fire a postback when they're clicked typically (hard to say without knowing the exact object you're using). Use an HTML input to fire your client side event, do your work, and then perform the postback from your JS code (with an appropriate ID to catch on the server side).

Something like this server side:

```
/// <summary>
/// Page init event, setup the core of the page.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected override void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    // See if we're in a postback.
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
      // If we have a target...
      if (Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] != null)
      {
        // See what the target is.
        switch (Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"])
        {
          case "btnGo":
            // Maybe make this a parameterless method rather than an event handler to avoid parameters that you don't need.
            btnGo_Click(null, null);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And client side:

```
function Go() {
    // Show loading...

    // Call server.
    __doPostBack("btnGo", "My Args");
    }
```

EDIT: As an alternative I think you can also add "return false;" after the client side event, such as:

btnGo.OnClientClick = "HideControlOnClick(this); return false;";

and that should stop the postback as well.